# How to import a cordova apache plugin in IBM worklight?

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I have a cordova apache plugin. I dn't know how to import that file into MFP.
Any idea? Thanks

Comment: which MFP version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Worklight does not support Cordova's Plug-man to install Cordova plug-ins, you can follow the instructions provided in the following blog post, detailing the steps needed to take in order to manually add a plug-in in a way that will work. Note that it may differ from plug-in to plug-in: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/03/integrating-3rd-party-cordova-plug-ins/